# ColdFusion - SQL execution time varies by Application

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I'm running 2 separate sites/Applications under a single install of ColdFusion.

The execution time of SQL statements is different depending on the site they are run in.

If, for example, I run the following SQL Server command:

```
DBCC USEROPTIONS
```

Site 1 consistently executes in 0 or 1 ms:

[image]

Site 2 consistently executes in around 20 ms:

[image]

Both sites are using the same CF datasource set up in the CFIDE admin.

What else could account for the variation I am seeing?

Thanks,
Stu

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you run the page in any order? (ie. site 1 then site 2 then site 1 etc...) The applications on the 2 sites are the same?

Comment: Order of requests doesn't make a difference - and the behaviour persists even after CF app server restart. The applications on the 2 sites are *not* the same

Comment: when you're saying 2 sites it is not 2 different instances? Are you doing that query just when your app start in both cases? if not try this...

Comment: Is the second site generally underperforming? Or are you asking a more theoretical question. In other words, is this reported execution time issue a problem for site number 2? I would guess that below 20mils the accuracy of the execution time is suspect. When I see 15mils I sort of mentally assume that means "as low as can be measured without being 0"... so something like the order in which the debug info is collected might be enough to affect it.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - not just theoretical. I'm seeing periodic timeouts on certain stored procedures, but only when they are called from Site 2. The DBCC USEROPTIONS example was just for simplicity - in reality the executions times are much greater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I think I've found the reason for this.

In the Site 1 example another DB query had run before my test query.

In the Site 2 example the test query was the first to run.

Presumably the extra ms are just DB connection setup overhead.

Mystery solved. Not the smoking gun I was looking for.